# Adding more emphasis on most recent data in CNNs

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, cnn, convolution

I am using a CNN for multivariate time series analysis. The input size is (`batch_size, 500, 30`) i.e 30 variables and 500 time steps. I would like to put more emphasis on recent data and less on the past data.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use Keras - `sample_weight` parameter in [fit()](http://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit) method.

That parameter specifies which steps are more important.